# how to display the entire variable with space in textbox in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display the value with space in text box.database value is "usman road".
But in text box it shows only "usman".

```
            $value="select * from employee where e_id=$ses";
            $value1=mysql_query($value);
            $vfet=mysql_fetch_assoc($value1);

   echo '<p>First Name<input type="text" name="f" size=18 maxlength=50 style="background-color:transparent;border:0px solid white;" readonly value='.$vfet['e_first_name'].'></p>';
```

Comment: Try echo $vfet['e_first_name'] just above the input and see what comes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put quotes around value

```
... value="'.$vfet['e_first_name'].'"...
```

What you have is is invalid html and breaks the value on the space

```
... value='.$vfet['e_first_name'].' ...  // value = john doe
                                                 ^
```

After making the change it will become

```
value = "john doe"
```

To use unquoted value for attributes you have to follow the following HTML specifications

> An unquoted attribute value is specified by providing the following
> parts in exactly the following order:
>
> 1.an attribute name
>
> 2.zero or more space characters
>
> 3.a single "=" character
>
> 4.zero or more space characters
>
> 5.an attribute value
>
> In addition to the general requirements for attribute values, an
> unquoted attribute value has the following restrictions:
>
> • must not > contain any literal space characters
>
> • must not contain any """, "'",> "=", ">", "<", or "`", characters
>
> must not be the empty string

Since your value has a space, it breaks the rules :)

**[Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#attr-value-unquoted)**

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_match

```
 <?php

$a = "usman road";
$b = "SamSpade";
$c = "usman\t\t\troad";

var_dump(preg_match('/\s/',$a));
var_dump(preg_match('/\s/',$b));
var_dump(preg_match('/\s/',$c));
```

Ouput:

```
int(1)
int(0)
int(1)
```