# PHP file in word press displaying variable with space in

Tags: php, html, variables

Hi really sorry for asking what probably is a simple thing.

The html below ( `group=".$object->organizer_name.">` ) 
outputs the following :

```
<div id="buy-ticket" group="Test" with="" space=""
```

When it should be =

```
<div id="buy-ticket" group="Test with space"
```

I've looked at this artical :
[how to display the entire variable with space in textbox in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27243650/how-to-display-the-entire-variable-with-space-in-textbox-in-php)

and tried to use `.$object[organizer_name.]` instead but with no luck :-(

I'm guessing its something to do with the placement of the `"` and `'`

Thanks for any help !!

Full snipet of code below :

```
if(!empty($ORGMeta['evcal_org_exlink'])) {
    $orgNAME = "<span class='evo_card_organizer_name_t'>
                    <a ".( $newdinwow )." href='" . evo_format_link($ORGMeta['evcal_org_exlink']) . "'>".$object->organizer_name."</a>
                </span>";
} else {
    $orgNAME = "<div id='buy-ticket' group=".$object->organizer_name.">   
                    <div id='selectTicketValidation' class='validation'></div>
                    <div id='selectTicketGroup' class='selector'>
                        <p>The ticket selector is loading.</p>
                        <p>Please check you have JavaScript enabled.</p>
                        <p><a href='javascript:TygitTickets.start();'>click here to manually start the ticket selector</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div id='selectTicketSubGroup' class='selector'></div>
                    <div id='selectTicketDate' class='selector'></div>
                    <div id='selectTicketTime' class='selector'></div>
                    <div id='selectTicketTypes' class='selector'></div>
                </div>";
}
```

Comment: Can you improve the formatting of your code? Currently, I cannot see what happens and why your html outputs `=`

Answer (score 0):

If this is inside an echo that uses double quotes for strings (which i suppose it is), you need add single quotes for the `group` attribute as follows:

```
<div id='buy-ticket' group='".$object->organizer_name."'>
```

The complete thing would then be something like `echo "<div id='buy-ticket' group='".$object->organizer_name."'>";`

ADDITION AFTER EDIT OF QUESTION:

Yes, it is the way I thought. So this line

```
$orgNAME = "<div id='buy-ticket' group=".$object->organizer_name.">
```

should be

```
$orgNAME = "<div id='buy-ticket' group='".$object->organizer_name."'>
[ etc. ]
```

Comment: You are welcome! If my answer helped you, please give it an upvote or/and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
$orgNAME = "<div id='buy-ticket' group='$object->organizer_name'> ";
```

this will work fine since you are using `"` or you can do it like that as well:

```
  $orgNAME = "<div id='buy-ticket' group='".$object->organizer_name."'> ";
```